# Python: "HVZ" Tag when using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I am new to natural language processing, and when experimenting with combining word taggers I came across the tag "HVZ". The tag is not in the Penn Treebank listing.. any idea what it means?

Here is the sentence I tagged:

```
Tom the cat has blue eyes.
```

and the result:

```
[('Tom', 'NP'), ('the', 'AT'), ('cat', 'NN'), ('has', 'HVZ'), ('blue', 'JJ'), ('eyes', 'NNS')]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [The Brown Corpus Tag-set](https://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/ccalas/tagsets/brown.html):

> HVZ
>   verb "to have", present tense, 3rd person singular

Examples:

> has hath